# Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli::fetchAssoc() I don't want primary keys as array indexes!

Tags: zend-framework

According to ZF documentation when using fetchAssoc() the first column in the result set must contain unique values, or else rows with duplicate values in the first column will overwrite previous data.

I don't want this, I want my array to be indexed 0,1,2,3... I don't need rows to be unique because I won't modify them and won't save them back to the DB.

Answer (score 3):

According to ZF documentation fetchAll() (when using the default fetch mode, which is in fact FETCH_ASSOC) is equivalent to fetchAssoc(). BUT IT'S NOT.
I've used print_r()function to reveal the truth.

```
print_r($db->fetchAll('select col1, col2 from table'));
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [col1] => 1
            [col2] => 2
        )
)
```

So:

1. fetchAll() is what I wanted.
2. There's a bug in ZF documentation

Comment: AFAICT There's no "bug" in the documentation, you're just not interpreting it correctly (so maybe they could rephrase it to make things absolutely clear). fetchAll() with FETCH_ASSOC doesn't do anything with the keys of the main array (so all rows will be returned), whereas fetchAssoc() uses the value of the first column in the query as index for the main array.

Answer (score 0):

From http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html
`The fetchAssoc() method returns data in an array of associative arrays, regardless of what   value you have set for the fetch mode, **using the first column as the array index**.`

So if you put
`$result = $db->fetchAssoc(

        'SELECT some_column, other_column FROM table'

);`

you'll have as result an array like this

`$result['some_column']['other_column']`

Comment: The result of that is `$result[some_column_value] = [ 'some_column' => some_column_value, 'other_column' => other_column_value ];`, as I have recently found out.